# Button`s content on change

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm

I have a WPF-MVVM application and I am binding the content of my buttons with a ViewModel.
Sometimes it happens that new content contains text inside "()".

```
   <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding UnfinishedText}"
                            FontSize="22" Grid.Column="7"
                            Height="Auto" Foreground="White"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}"
                            Command="{Binding ShowUnfinishedProcedures}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow}"/>


 public string ToDoText
        {
            get { return _toDoText; }
            set
            {
                _toDoText = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ToDoText");
            }
        }
```

Let's say I've binded new content: "Hello(60)". Is it possible to change foreground in this example just for text in brackets?

I planned to use `Button.ContentChanged` event but it doesn't exist.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An addition to Alex's suggestion.

Create two properties in your View Model, one for text and one for value inside brackets.

here Message and count for example.

Bind two properties as shown below to keep it simple.

```
 <Button.Content>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding Message}"/>(            
        <Run Text="{Binding Count}" Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"/>)            
    </TextBlock>
 </Button.Content>
```

Also you can append some static text if required.

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="StatiContent" Foreground="Blue"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Message}"/>(            
        <Run Text="{Binding Count}" Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"/>)            
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

In WPF you can nest `TextBlock`s and apply different styles and bindings to them.

So in your ViewModel you can have two separate properties each bound to different `TextBlock` with its own style:

```
private string _message = null;
public string Message
{
    get
    {
        return _message;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_message == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _message = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Message);
    }
}

private int _count = 0;
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        return _count;
    }
    set
    {
        _count = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Count);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0"
        FontSize="22" Grid.Column="7"
        Height="Auto" Foreground="White"
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}"
        Command="{Binding ShowUnfinishedProcedures}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow}">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock><TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" /> (<TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" Style="{StaticResource CountTextBlockStyle}" />)</TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```